# Dependency Issue : DexArchiveMergerException

Tags: android, exception, android-multidex

I have created a new Project with below dependency included :

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

and at the time of running the app, am getting below error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

What might be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaimin, hope you have enabled multidex in your app gradle file using..

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Still if it is not resolved, you add the following code:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.+'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, It's Working.